# SonarQube Plugin for TIBCO BusinessWorks5

Tags: sonarqube, tibco-business-works

I'm in need of implementing SonarQube for TIBCO. The current version of TIBCO we are using is 5.x . I'm unable to find any SonarQube TIBCO BW5 plugin. I'm trying hard for a week of all possible means to construct it. But nothing helped?
Can you please share.

Note : I'm able to find links for TIBCO BW6 version. I need the sonarqube plugin for TIBCO BW5 version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a Tibco authored plugin, but [BWCodescanner](https://bwcodescanner.com) has a scanner plugin that integrates with SonarCube.

Feature list - https://bwcodescanner.com/tibco-bw/governance-code-scanner/features

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Ya I've already gone through the above link, but even for testing when we tried with our simple code , it asks to buy the enterprise version :( .  For BW 5.7 i'm still searching for the right plugin

Comment: @Bharath, are you looking for free / open source plugin or enterprise version. BW Code Scanner plugin for TIBCO BW5 is paid enterprise version. We recently had a demo with them as part of evaluation and looks like it integrates seamlessly with SonarQube and Jenkins to break builds if code violations of a given severity threshold are met. We couldn't find any free SonarQube plugins for BW 5.x